# forge modding 1.20.1 - Trying to set up a dev environement to make a mod with xaeros minimap as dependancy, but xaeros fail to load correctly

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

here is my issue:
I've made an intelij project with the minecraft plugin and i choose architectury forge and fabric. I was trying to add xaeros minimap as dependency, and i use cursemaven to do that. I think this is not the issue. Here is the part i made to add xaeros as dependancy in the build.gradle :

```java
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://cursemaven.com"
        content {
            includeGroup "curse.maven"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    forge "net.minecraftforge:forge:${rootProject.forge_version}"
    // Remove the next line if you don't want to depend on the API
    modApi "dev.architectury:architectury-forge:${rootProject.architectury_version}"
    common(project(path: ":common", configuration: "namedElements")) { transitive false }
    shadowCommon(project(path: ":common", configuration: "transformProductionForge")) { transitive = false }
    implementation "curse.maven:xaerosminimap-263420:4763283"
}
```

and when i click on run client in loom and forge in gradle project, it give me an error; here are the log :

```
[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:red_sandstone_wall#east=low,north=tall,south=tall,up=false,waterlogged=false,west=none': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:bell#attachment=double_wall,facing=east,powered=false': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:polished_blackstone_brick_wall#east=none,north=tall,south=none,up=true,waterlogged=false,west=tall': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:fire#age=0,east=false,north=false,south=false,up=true,west=true': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:sandstone_wall#east=tall,north=low,south=tall,up=true,waterlogged=false,west=low': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:end_stone_brick_wall#east=none,north=low,south=tall,up=false,waterlogged=true,west=tall': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:andesite_wall#east=low,north=tall,south=low,up=true,waterlogged=false,west=low': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:polished_andesite_stairs#facing=west,half=bottom,shape=inner_right,waterlogged=true': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:redstone_wire#east=up,north=up,power=6,south=side,west=up': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:carved_pumpkin#facing=south': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:end_stone_brick_stairs#facing=south,half=bottom,shape=outer_right,waterlogged=true': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get config value before config is loaded.
This error is currently only thrown in the development environment, to avoid breaking published mods.
In a future version, this will also throw in the production environment.

[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to bake model: 'minecraft:deepslate_brick_wall#east=low,north=low,south=low,up=false,waterlogged=false,west=tall': 
[18:50:54] [Worker-Main-11/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.ModelEvent$ModifyBakingResult to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Missing sound for event: minecraft:item.goat_horn.play
[18:50:54] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Missing sound for event: minecraft:entity.goat.screaming.horn_break
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [mojang/Library]: OpenAL initialized on device OpenAL Soft on 5 - HP Z27n (2- AMD High Definition Audio Device)
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Sound engine started
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.sound.SoundEngineLoadEvent to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/signs.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shield_patterns.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/banner_patterns.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 1024x1024x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/armor_trims.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 128x64x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/decorated_pot.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/chest.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/beds.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shulker_boxes.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.ModelEvent$BakingCompleted to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$CreateSkullModels to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityRenderersEvent$AddLayers to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/ShaderInstance]: Shader rendertype_entity_translucent_emissive could not find sampler named Sampler2 in the specified shader program.
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.RegisterShadersEvent to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/particles.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/paintings.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
[18:50:54] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 128x128x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/mob_effects.png-atlas
[18:50:54] [Render thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.fm.ModLoader/]: Cowardly refusing to send event net.minecraftforge.client.event.TextureStitchEvent$Post to a broken mod state
Negative index in crash report handler (28/30)
[18:50:54] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.co.ForgeMod/]: Preparing crash report with UUID c8707642-55ea-481e-9206-61e29fa9d39a
[18:50:54] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.cl.lo.ClientModLoader/]: Crash report saved to .\crash-reports\crash-2024-01-09_18.50.54-fml.txt
[18:50:54] [Render thread/FATAL] [ne.mi.co.ForgeMod/]: Preparing crash report with UUID 93eb93b2-b5aa-4c33-8209-d0ac0c331cc4
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 2024-01-09 18:50:54
Description: Mod loading error has occurred

java.lang.Exception: Mod Loading has failed
    at net.minecraftforge.logging.CrashReportExtender.dumpModLoadingCrashReport(CrashReportExtender.java:60) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23192%23199!/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.client.loading.ClientModLoader.completeModLoading(ClientModLoader.java:143) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23192%23199!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$new$4(Minecraft.java:571) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:architectury.mixins.json:MixinMinecraft,pl:mixin:A,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.Util.ifElse(Util.java:421) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:unprotect:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.lambda$new$5(Minecraft.java:564) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:architectury.mixins.json:MixinMinecraft,pl:mixin:A,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraftforge.client.loading.ForgeLoadingOverlay.render(ForgeLoadingOverlay.java:146) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23192%23199!/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer.render(GameRenderer.java:954) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1146) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:architectury.mixins.json:MixinMinecraft,pl:mixin:A,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:718) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:mixin,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A,re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:mixin:APP:architectury.mixins.json:MixinMinecraft,pl:mixin:A,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:218) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.mappings.1_20_1.layered+hash.40359-v2-forge-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23193!/:?] {re:classloading,pl:unprotect:A,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.runTarget(CommonLaunchHandler.java:111) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23104!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.clientService(CommonLaunchHandler.java:99) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23104!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.devService(ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.java:19) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23104!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonDevLaunchHandler.lambda$makeService$7(CommonDevLaunchHandler.java:135) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23104!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:30) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:108) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:78) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar%23109!/:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:141) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) ~[?:?] {}
    at dev.architectury.transformer.TransformerRuntime.main(TransformerRuntime.java:219) ~[?:?] {}


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at xaero.common.effect.EffectsRegister.registerEffect(EffectsRegister.java:30) ~[xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar%23200!/:23.8.1] {re:classloading}
-- MOD xaerominimap --
Details:
    Caused by 0: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?] {}
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:68) ~[javafmllanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23194!/:?] {}
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$10(ModContainer.java:123) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23197!/:?] {}
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) ~[?:?] {}
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) ~[?:?] {re:computing_frames}
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) ~[?:?] {re:computing_frames}
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) ~[?:?] {}

    Mod File: /C:/Users/groma/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/curse.maven/xaerosminimap-263420/4763283/4dbb993148d97c4dbe722912e9ebb4b9b2cc39bb/xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar
    Failure message: Xaero's Minimap (xaerominimap) has failed to load correctly
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    Mod Version: 23.8.1
    Mod Issue URL: https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/xaeros-minimap/issues
    Exception message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String net.minecraft.resources.ResourceLocation.m_135815_()'
Stacktrace:
    at xaero.common.effect.EffectsRegister.registerEffect(EffectsRegister.java:30) ~[xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar%23200!/:23.8.1] {re:classloading}
    at xaero.common.effect.EffectsRegister.registerEffects(EffectsRegister.java:14) ~[xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar%23200!/:23.8.1] {re:classloading}
    at xaero.minimap.XaeroMinimap.<init>(XaeroMinimap.java:144) ~[xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar%23200!/:23.8.1] {re:classloading}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:68) ~[javafmllanguage-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23194!/:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$10(ModContainer.java:123) ~[fmlcore-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar%23197!/:?] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) ~[?:?] {re:computing_frames}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) ~[?:?] {re:computing_frames}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) ~[?:?] {}


-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.20.1
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.20.1
    Operating System: Windows 11 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 17.0.9, JetBrains s.r.o.
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), JetBrains s.r.o.
    Memory: 669061120 bytes (638 MiB) / 1971322880 bytes (1880 MiB) up to 8573157376 bytes (8176 MiB)
    CPUs: 12
    Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
    Processor Name: AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT 6-Core Processor            
    Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0
    Microarchitecture: Zen 2
    Frequency (GHz): 3.79
    Number of physical packages: 1
    Number of physical CPUs: 6
    Number of logical CPUs: 12
    Graphics card #0 name: Radeon RX 570 Series
    Graphics card #0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. (0x1002)
    Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 4095.00
    Graphics card #0 deviceId: 0x67df
    Graphics card #0 versionInfo: DriverVersion=31.0.21905.1001
    Memory slot #0 capacity (MB): 16384.00
    Memory slot #0 clockSpeed (GHz): 3.20
    Memory slot #0 type: DDR4
    Memory slot #1 capacity (MB): 16384.00
    Memory slot #1 clockSpeed (GHz): 3.20
    Memory slot #1 type: DDR4
    Virtual memory max (MB): 48964.80
    Virtual memory used (MB): 41458.48
    Swap memory total (MB): 16275.82
    Swap memory used (MB): 1740.83
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    ModLauncher: 10.0.9+10.0.9+main.dcd20f30
    ModLauncher launch target: forgeclientuserdev
    ModLauncher naming: mcp
    ModLauncher services: 
        mixin-patched-0.8.5.10.jar mixin PLUGINSERVICE 
        eventbus-6.0.5.jar eventbus PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar slf4jfixer PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar object_holder_definalize PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar runtime_enum_extender PLUGINSERVICE 
        unprotect-1.2.0.jar unprotect PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar capability_token_subclass PLUGINSERVICE 
        accesstransformers-8.0.4.jar accesstransformer PLUGINSERVICE 
        fmlloader-1.20.1-47.2.0.jar runtimedistcleaner PLUGINSERVICE 
        modlauncher-10.0.9.jar mixin TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
        modlauncher-10.0.9.jar ForgeLoomMixinRemapperInjector TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
        modlauncher-10.0.9.jar fml TRANSFORMATIONSERVICE 
    FML Language Providers: 
        minecraft@1.0
        lowcodefml@null
        javafml@null
    Mod List: 
        forge-1.20.1-47.2.0-minecraft-merged-1.20.1-loom.m|Minecraft                     |minecraft                     |1.20.1              |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
        main                                              |open pac claims machines      |open_pac_claims_machines      |1.0-SNAPSHOT        |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
        2288935808956264307.jar                           |generated_a08bb73             |generated_a08bb73             |1                   |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
                                                          |Forge                         |forge                         |47.2.0              |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
        xaerosminimap-263420-4763283.jar                  |Xaero's Minimap               |xaerominimap                  |23.8.1              |ERROR     |Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
        architectury-forge-9.1.12.jar                     |Architectury                  |architectury                  |9.1.12              |COMMON_SET|Manifest: NOSIGNATURE
    Crash Report UUID: 93eb93b2-b5aa-4c33-8209-d0ac0c331cc4
    FML: 47.2
```

i tried to change the version of forge, of xaeros ect, it doesn't work.